# Как вставить видео в Delphi и какой формат лучше?

Tags: mediaplayer, delphi

Как вставить видео в Delphi, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку грузилось определенное, и какой формат лучше для видео (конвертация + звук) и какие компоненты вставлять на форму?

Comment: Дубликат? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/206922/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%be-%d0%b2-delphi?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Ну компонент: самое простое, наверно, MediaPlayer. Сначала настроить, куда выводить видео: свойство Display = Panel1. На кнопку:

- имя файла mediaplayer.FileName:='video.wmv';
- открытие плеера MediaPlayer.Open;
- проигрывание MediaPlayer.Play;