# Как вставить видео в delphi?

Tags: delphi

как добавить видео в формате mp4 на Delphi?

Answer (score 1):

на форму TMediaPlayer и TPanel

```
MediaPlayer1.DeviceType:= dtAutoSelect;
MediaPlayer1.FileName := 'C:\test.avi';
MediaPlayer1.Display:=Panel1;
MediaPlayer1.Open;
MediaPlayer1.Play;
```

c mp4 не пробовал но поидее должно сработать хотя могу и ошибаться